# Using a external c library in Rcpp

Tags: linker, rcpp

I want to use a c function  "rpg_hybrid" that correspond to R library BayesLogit rpg (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/BayesLogit/docs/rpg) in my Rcpp code. I have include LogitWrapper.h  and also the library BayesLogit.so to linking stage. GCC still cannot find the rpg_hybrid.

Comment: Did you install the package `BayesLogit` from source or did you install the CRAN binary? You might need to try installing `BayesLogit` from source. In addition, try compiling with the `-v` option to see if GCC is finding paths and looking in the right places as expected.

Comment: We need more details, as @KevinUshey suggested. Right now the question is unanswerable.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was treating *.so file as library file, it should be treated as object file. Both CRAN binary or install from source works. How does I can make this automated in Rcpp package release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it seems like you've solved your problem, I'll provide an answer in the context of developing an R package that you might want to e.g. release to CRAN.

---

Basically, the authors of `BayesLogit` need to explicitly make such routines available for other package authors. This is described in [section 5.4.2 of R-exts](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Linking-to-native-routines-in-other-packages). From what I can see from the source code, this has not been done, so you will be unable to call the native C/C++ code in that package in a portable, and hence CRAN-acceptable, way.

Your options are:

1. Contact the package authors and ask if they can make this routine available,
2. Copy the source to your own package and give attribution; if you do this, make sure the licence you use is compatible with theirs.

As an aside, Rcpp also has facilities for making source code available in a header only way. The package authors might be convinced to make some routines available by using [Rcpp Attributes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf), as it provides a simple mechanism for allowing other authors to use C++ code in a package; see section 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

A student in my class pointed me to your query.  Although I haven't had time to do the things Kevin/Dirk suggested, I have posted a more user-friendly C++ API to my Github page.
See https://github.com/jgscott/helloPG

This comes in the form of a R package skeleton which can easily be modified.  I hope this will be a workable standby in the interim, until we can modify BayesLogit appropriately.

-James